# MapInfo equivalent of SQL 'AS' statement

Tags: mapinfo, sql

I'm trying to execute a SQL query in MapInfo, and want to change some of the column names to something more readable. The SQL command 'AS' doesn't seem to work - is there a MapInfo equivalent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MapInfo SQL doesn't use the AS keyword. You can just add the alias in quotes after the column name.

```
SELECT col1 "Bar" FROM Foo
```